# RethinkDB returns incorrect results in Data Explorer with r.row

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdbdash

Environments tested in: RethinkDB 2.3.5 installed on Ubuntu Xenial, same tested on MacOS Sierra.

The below done on clean install with one record added to test database:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMAMH.png)

Dashboard Data Explorer exact match query without r.row does find the record.

```
 1 row returned. Displaying rows 1-1
{

    "id": "f26a33f4-5add-442e-93b6-5fb93e817fb8" ,
    "myfield1": 1 ,
    "myfield2": "content"

}
```

With Python3 it works with r.row:

```
>>> import rethinkdb
>>> conn = r.connect()
>>> r.db('test').table('test').filter(r.row['myfield1'] == 1).run(conn)
<rethinkdb.net.DefaultCursor object at 0x7f8a95839438 (done streaming):
 [{'myfield1': 1, 'myfield2': 'content', 'id': 'f26a33f4-5add-442e-93b6-5fb93e817fb8'}]>
>>>
```

This means that data is set correctly.

However, Dashboard Data Explorer FAILS on filter with r.row: That's the result with "No records found" rather then expected "1 row returned. Displaying rows 1-1":

[Failure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8BoW.png)

Could you help me to find what's the correct way of working with r.row in Dashboard Data Explorer or confirm that it is actual bug (pretty major then)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard uses Javascript syntax and does not comprehend Python. So, the query shoudl be put in Javascript:

instead of Python syntax

```
r.db('test').table('test').filter(r.row['myfield1'] == 1)
```

Dashboard accespts Javascript syntax:

```
r.db('test').table('test').filter(r.row("myfield1").eq(1))
```